# WSO2 API Manager - Visibility of APIs

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a specific question dealing with WSO2 API Manager. Is there anyway to enable publishers to restrict their APIs' visibilities user-wise rather than role-wise?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

In WSO2 API Manager,controlling of API visibility has implemented by re-using the underlying WSO2 Carbon based role based authorization model. However still you can restrict API visibility for a particular users group by assign them to a particular role and define that role in APIManager as to restrict the API visibility..May I know what's the reason for preferring to have user-wise controlling for API visibility rather current way of role-wise?

Thanks;

/Lalaji

Comment: Thanks Lalaji for your reply. We are aiming to use API Manager in an Internet-scale project, not inside an organization. Therefore, we need to track and manage users independently from their roles, as well.

Comment: The API visibility looks like security by obscurity (the role doesn't really restrict the user editing the restricted API). There's a way how to gain access to the API even when not visible :(